# pointer and char array

Tags: c

I am using gcc 4.9.2-10 deb8u1 compiler to compile
Here is my code

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    int main(){
    char *s;
    char sa[10] , sb[10];
    scanf("%s", sa);
    printf("line\n");
    scanf("%s", sb);
    printf("%s   %s", sa, sb);
}
```

Above code is no any problem if char is under the space provided

However

```
    scanf("%s", s);
    printf("line\n");
    scanf("%s", sa);
    printf("%s   %s", s, sa);
```

Input:
$: 
Hu

Result:
line
(null)   Hu

Someone could told me what happen about second code wrong .?
I cannot figure out why i cannt input second one .. Thx a lot .!

Comment: Is this C or C++?

Comment: Please provide a **complete** code example, this means you should have a `main()` function.

Comment: allocate space to pointer variable

Comment: You said "code is no any problem if char is under the space provided" - Are you suggesting longer inputs cuase the problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic because it asks for help diagnosing incomplete fragments of code (and, as a bonus, because you maybe `scanf()`ing to an uninitialised pointer).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14707427/taking-string-input-in-char-pointer#14707497 check out this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Taking string input in char pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14707427/taking-string-input-in-char-pointer)

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the input format specifier '%s' and/or '%[...]' always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer.  This is for two reasons; a) those specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input b) to avoid any chance of a buffer overflow

Comment: @user3629249 I would add: 3) Never use `scanf` for user input.

Comment: Hint: What is the value of pointer `s` when it is passed to `scanf("%s", s);`?

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%s", s);` This is writing characters to where a uninitialized pointer is pointing.  This (probably) will result in a seg fault event.  Similar considerations exist for: `printf("%s   %s", s, sa);`

Comment: @melpomene it is C. I place it in C++ catagory so that more notice it XD

Comment: @szema, DO NOT place into categories where it does not belong.  C and C++ are two very different languages

Comment: @jasinthpremkumar thx a lost its helpful for its simple question ...!

Comment: @szema it is called "tag spamming" - using irrelevant tags "so that more notice it".

Answer (score 1):

In you code

```
char *s;
char sa[10] , sb[10];
```

you can't do much with `s`.

```
scanf("%s", sa);
```

is ok, provided the input fits. You can jump through a few hoops, reading the inputs in chunks in a loop if it might be longer (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621394/how-to-prevent-scanf-causing-a-buffer-overflow-in-c))

However, in you "However" section of the question you try

```
scanf("%s", s);
```

Since `s` doesn't point to memory - you'd need to have allocated some - you have undefined behaviour, so anything could happen.

Answer (score 0):

*I cannot figure out why i cannt input second one* ? because `s` is not initialize and not having any valid address & doing `scanf()` on that results in **undefined behaviour**.

First allocate the memory and then scan the user input.

```
int main() {
        char *s; /* its un initialized */
        s = malloc(size); /* this you  need to do ? specify the size value */
        fgets(s,size,stdin);/* its advisable as its not having overflow problem */
        printf("%s\n",s);
        /* once job is done , free it by calling free(s) */
        free(s);
        return 0;
}
```

Use `fgets()` instead of `scanf()` to scan the user input for the reason listed in comments.

Comment: And consider freeing it afterwards too

Comment: `scanf("%s",s);` has overflow problems like `gets()` as they do not limit intput.  Both should be avoided.

Comment: limit can be specified in `size` part of  `malloc()` , isn't it ?  Then Op should use `fgets()` instead of `scanf()`

Comment: "limit can be specified in size part of malloc()" --> No.  The size allocated with `malloc()` is not known to `scanf()` unless _somehow_ that information is passed to the function.  Maybe by the format of `scanf()`.  Better still, consider `fgets()`.

Comment: I got your point about `scanf()`. Are you suggesting we shouldn't use `scanf()` on malloc'ed memory ? whats the other way

Comment: "Are you suggesting we shouldn't use scanf() on malloc'ed memory ?"  --> Using `scanf("%s")` on any memory is weak programing practice - regardless of the source of the memory.

Comment: So why there is a `scanf()` at first place at all, just asking !!. If _regardless of the source of the memory_ either statically allocated memory or dynamic memory.

Comment: One last point, So Its advisable and consider as good practice to use `fgets()` instead of `scanf()` on malloc'ed  memory or even static array,  correct If am wrong.

Comment: @achal It's good practice to never use `scanf`, especially not for user input. Most users are bad at producing perfectly formatted input.

Comment: yes @melpomene got your point. Thanks.

Comment: 'Why do insecure functions (still) exist?' Let's think about that for a few seconds! Usually it's because no one either thought or cared about security back in the Stone Age when C was first standardised, and although better things are available now, the old stuff is left around because everyone's paranoid about breaking backwards compatibility (sometimes to a quite excessive extent, if you ask me).

Comment: Rightly pointed @underscore_d I got your point.